# Add photos to a post with only one shared photo (from the desktop or otherwise)

Tags: google-plus

I want to know if it's possible to add more photos to a post that got created by sharing a single photo. I can't find a way.

In contrast, when I share a couple (or more) photos in a post, a kind of pseudo-album is created. I can always go back later and add photos to this pseudo-album, and (after a small while) the new content gets reflected on the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the lightbox view select "photos from posts" that should take you to an album view where you can add photos.

[image: Photos from posts]

[image: Add photos]

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is possible anymore, after the change to move photos out of G+.

Comment: The [Picasa Web UI](https://picasaweb.google.com/) will still let you do this to.